# Upload file from browser, process w python, back to the frontend for user download

Tags: javascript, python, html

What is the most basic way for a user to upload a file from the browser,
then I will process it with python on the backend, which will generate some new files,
and then send them back to the frontend for the user to be able to download them.

Preferably using http.server or node.js

process:

user uploads file
shell determines that a file has been uploaded
runs a python script that generates some new files
these appear in the browser
user downloads them

Comment: What part do you not know how to do? Call Python from `node.js` or `http.server`? Accept a file upload? Send a file back to the user? There's so many individual steps here, but you're asking about all of them at once. Just ask about what you specifically need help with. Otherwise this is way too broad of a question. We have no idea if you have any experience at all with `node.js` or `http.server`, so even if we do provide a solution, there's no guarantee you'll understand it. I hope that the [tour] and [ask] page, and the [mre] page, can make it clear what kind of info your question needs.

Comment: thanks for the quick response, I will work on this and revise!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.